# Show that an affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is a Borel set.

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, affine-geometry, borel-sets

Everything is in the title.

I was thinking of using the fact that an affine subspace of $\mathbb{R}^d$ is the set of solutions to a system of linear equations, but I can't figure out how to describe those solutions in a way that helps.

I am quite new to affine subspaces so I don't really know where to start.

Thanks :)

Comment: forget affineness for a moment. Do you believe that subspaces are Borel sets?

Comment: The "set of solutions to a system of linear equations" is a good idea! You can use this to write an affine subspace as the pre-image of a certain set under a certain map. These have some nice properties, which will tell you something about the affine subspace...

Comment: The empty set is a borel set because it is closed. But how can I generate a subspace with open and closed sets, it's mind-boggling

Comment: Alex, how much do you know about closed sets? Do you know the definition? Some examples? Some techniques for showing a set is closed? Which affine subspaces of $\Bbb R^2$ are closed, do you think?

Comment: It is not clear what you are allowed to use. For example, can you use the fact that closed subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ are Borel, or are you asked to prove that? Can you assume that affine subsets of $\mathbb{R}^d$ are closed, or are you asked to prove that? To show that solutions to $Ax=b$ form a closed set, you might start by saying "Suppose $x^*$ is a limit point of the solution set, so there is a sequence of solutions $\{x[1], x[2], x[3], ...\}$ that converge to $x^*$. We want to show $x^*$ is also a solution."